# Can power set of any set equals to $\phi$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In my topology quiz this question was asked and I couldn't do it right. So, I am posting it here.

> Let A be any set . Let P(A) be the power set of A, that is the set of all subsets of A, Then how is the statement" P(A)=$\phi$ for some A" a false statement?

I think if A =$\phi$ then P(A) is also $\phi$ but in answer key it is marked as false ?

Why?

Comment: $\emptyset \subseteq \emptyset \implies \emptyset \in P(\emptyset)$, so $P(\emptyset)$ is not empty.

Comment: Because the power-set of empty set has one element: the empty set itself because the empty set is a subset of every set, included of itself.

Comment: In general $\emptyset, A \subseteq A$, so $\emptyset, A \in \mathcal P(A) \ne \emptyset$.

Comment: If it helps, recall that if a set $A$ has $n$ elements then $P(A)$ has $2^n$ elements.  And $2^0 = 1$.

Comment: @aman Maybe you wanted to say $A=\emptyset \implies P(A)=\{\emptyset\}\neq \emptyset.$

Comment: @mfl Yes I had no clue how to do the curly brackets never mind

Comment: @aman Write \{ a \} to get $\{a\}.$

Comment: @mfl why {$\phi $}$\neq  \phi$?

Comment: $\{\emptyset\}$ has one element which is $\emptyset.$ But $\emptyset$ does not have any element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The powerset of a set $X$ has $2^{|X|}$ elements.
So the powerset of any set has at least one element (as $2^0=1$), and therefore can not be empty.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $\exists A$ such that $\mathcal P(A)=\emptyset$. This means that there is no $B$ such that $B\subseteq A.$ But we know that $A\subseteq A$, hence there does exist a $B(=A)$ which is a contradiction. Therefore no $A$ exists such that $\mathcal P(A)=\emptyset$.